# which ubuntu version for oracle application express

Tags: oracle

I am new to Linux and want to set up a simple (hassle free) development environment for Oracle's Application Express.  As a personal development environment, I do not anticipate any more than one or two users at a time.

O/S must support local access to the database as well as remote access to the database.

Would Ubuntu Desktop serve my purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have ubuntu server install And install the  tools which you want .

to have a gui you can install one desktop environment like ubuntu, kubuntu, xubuntu,lubuntu etc.